# How to serve an application subdirectory (127.0.0.1:8000/app-subdirectory) from the root URL?

Tags: nginx

I'm confused how to make this happen. Most everyone on the net seems to want to serve a subdirectory (example.com/my-subdirectory) towards various app roots.

I want example.com/foo to be proxied to 127.0.0.1/my-subdirectory/foo transparently.

Any pointers?

I have tried just about every combination of proxy_pass and proxy_redirect :(

I feel this is very close

```
201      rewrite /(.*) /my-subdirectory/$1 break;
202      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
203      proxy_redirect off;
205      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

But unfortunately it's rewriting the URL on the browser too.

### Update

I found out the proxy pass was working but my application was redirecting to HTTPS, making most of my debugging useless. I would change a setting in nginx, and find confusing output, redirect loops, etc., as nginx was going through the listen 443 rules.

Now that I've disabled as much redirecting as possible in my app, things are back to sanity.

Thank you all for the downvotes - I don't think my question was particularly unworthy of asking and I only ask questions when I've spent at least 5 hours working through a problem with no end in sight.

Comment: You may enable [debuggin in Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Debugging) to see what's going on for each of the combination you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to rewrite anything if you just want to pass everything to your app. Try something along

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-subdirectory/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

To get your browser redirected to the correct host, (if your app doesn't do that), you should use

```
proxy_redirect default;
```

instead, which should be equivalent to

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-subdirectory/ /;
```

in your case. Check

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect

Comment: That's one of the first things I tried.. it redirects my browser to http:127.0.0.1:8000/my-subdirectory/. When I add the proper host, I no longer get redirected to 127.0.01, but the URL contains /my-subdirectory/ so visiting mysite.com/ takes me to mysite.com/my-subdirectory/ (and the path to the app is /my-subdirectory/). 

If the URL in the browser is /my-subdirectory/, my app should be seeing /my-subdirectory/my-subdirectory/. Arg!

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Making some progress.. I believe the problem was a redirect to HTTPS confusing the crap out of things. I disabled the APP redirecting to HTTPs and I'm getting somewhere!!

Comment: yes I believe all was working with a simply proxy_pass statement. The application was redirecting using what it thinks is say /my-directory/ which is why I never thought it was working at all... Thank you for your advice, it is very much appreciated. Let me dig into this a bit!

Comment: @YujiTomita: try `proxy_redirect   default;` instead of **off**, [see](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect)